# Error when using Speech Recognition Library at Pyhton

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr

def takecommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Escuchando...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 'None'
    
    query = query.lower()
    return query
```

I have this python function for trying to recognice voice when executing but every time i run the program i get the following exception even before i can speak:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\34644\Desktop\prueba 2.py", line 7, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\34644\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 189, in __exit__
    self.stream.close()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Basically the error comes when reaching the line "with sr.Microphone() as source:".  I would be grateful if someone knows why this is happening, thanks.

Comment: Please always include the whole traceback so we don't guess which line caused the error.

Comment: sorry, this is the whole tracebak:                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\34644\Desktop\prueba 2.py", line 7, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\34644\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 189, in __exit__
    self.stream.close()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close' ,                                
Basically the error occurs when reaching the line " with sr.Microphone() as source:"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include it formatted as code in the post, thanks

Comment: Oh okey, I´m new sorry, already done. Thanks

Comment: with sr.Microphone() as source: the error info show sr.Microphone is None

Comment: yeah but i have one connected so i dont know why it is failing

Comment: can you please print the value of `sr.Microphone()`? I suspect that your microphone is not registering / not available.